# How to avoid text jerk while scaling anchor in css transition?

Tags: html, css

I am trying increase scaling of links items while hovering over them with the help of CSS3 transition and scale(). Everything goes well except one annoying issue - the text within anchor elements increases with an ugly jerk which ruins the beauty of this cool effect. If you run the below code, you will see weird text shaking issue while hovering over pagination link. How can we prevent it from happening so?

```css
 .pagination {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  text-align:center;
 }
 
 .pagination a {
  padding:8px 16px; 
  margin:0 4px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000000;
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition:all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease;
  transition:all 0.3s ease;
 }
 
 .pagination a:hover {
  background-color:#ddd;
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform:scale(1.5);
  -o-transform:scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
  transform:scale(1.5);
 }
 
 .pagination span.current {
  padding:8px 16px; 
  margin:0 4px;
  border:1px solid #4CAF50;
  background-color:#4CAF50;
  color:#FFF;
 }
 
 .pagination span.disabled {
  padding:8px 16px; 
  margin:0 4px;
  border:1px solid #EEE;
  color:#DDD;
  /*display:none;*/ 
 }
```

```html
 <div class="pagination">
    <span class="disabled">&laquo; Prev</span>
    <span class="current">1</span>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
    <a href="#">6</a>
    <a href="#">7</a>
    <span>...</span>
    <a href="#">19</a>
    <a href="#">20</a>
    <a class="next" href="#">Next &raquo;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean that the text wobbles a bit after scaling? To tell you the truth, I hardly notice it; if you wouldn't have called my attention to it, I might not have noticed at all.

Comment: ha, very strange! it's so obvious to me that I could have noticed it even if you had created it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix for this is adding

```
.pagination {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
       -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
}

.pagination a {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
       -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

... to your CSS.

However, in your case, because the font is too small and thin, you'll still experience some jump in anti-aliasing, due to sub-pixel rendering at the end of the `transform` effect. The only effective solution for this case (if changing `font-family` or `font-weight` are not acceptable), is to change the `font-size` to decimal pixels until you find a value where the effect is less visible.

```
font-size: 14.5px;
```

... seems to be an improvement in your case. Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/to6yrgt1/).

Comment: Looks good. Yes, it is the anti-aliasing that causes it. It happens with images too when scaling up and down.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu, I don't think the issue has been fixed using your above provided solution. I can still observe text jerk. Yes it is anti-aliasing issue and its related to hardware resources. Not sure if it is still noticeable in retina display...

Comment: @user5307298, with what I provided it is barely noticeable in Chrome on Ubuntu, for `5`, `7` and `Next`. So it's possible that in your setup is more visible than on others. Can't know for sure, but it might have to do with both browser and/or system font settings, graphics card, etc. All I'm saying is the above is decent in most setups and, as a developer, there's not much more you can do about it.

Comment: I'm using FF 50 and it might be possible that it is more clearly noticeable in this version as compared to some others.

Comment: @user5307298, I've updated my answer with fully a prefixed version with maximum backwards compatibility. See if it helps. I don't know why, but ever since I read your question I assumed you're on Chrome. FF as preferred browser? OK! FF as web development tool? Thanks, but no, thanks...

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu, I had already added those vendors' prefixes myself in order to make the code compatible in different browsers. Yeah, I am on FF 50 since I like it for my development tasks. Sorry no Chrome at all - not at least for my work.